# i18n with UTF-8 encoded properties files in JSF 2.0 application

Tags: java, jsf, utf-8, internationalization, jsf-2

I am using jsf-ri 2.0.3 where Hebrew and Russian support is needed.
The problem is that I see gibberish on the screen instead of the correct text.

First of all I have defined bundles (*_locale.properties) for each language. The files is in UTF-8 encoding.
Secondly, I've defined the default and supported locales in faces-config.xml

```
<locale-config>
    <default-locale>iw</default-locale>
    <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    <supported-locale>ru</supported-locale>
</locale-config>
```

Than I've added a custom filter that will set the response charcter encoding to UTF-8.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And finally when I create a simple xhtml to debug the output I see a very strange results

```
<f:loadBundle basename="i18n.frontend.homepage" var="msg"/>
<strong>i18n: </strong><h:outputText value="#{msg.language}"/>
<br/>
<strong>Locale: </strong>
<h:outputText value="#{facesContext.externalContext.response.locale}"/>
<br/>
<strong>Encoding: </strong>
<h:outputText value="#{facesContext.externalContext.response.characterEncoding}"/>
```

The result is:

```
i18n: ×¢××¨××ª
Locale: en_US
Encoding: UTF-8
```

What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Right, you can create a custom [`ResourceBundle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) or use the native2ascii converter (if necessary with the Maven 2 plugin to make the conversion more transparent). Since the other answer only goes with the last approach in detail, here's another answer how you could create a custom `ResourceBundle` to load properties files as UTF-8 in a JSF 2.x application on Java SE 1.6 based environment.

`faces-config.xml`

```xml
<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>com.example.i18n.Text</base-name>
        <var>text</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

`com.example.i18n.Text`

```
package com.example.i18n;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.PropertyResourceBundle;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class Text extends ResourceBundle {

    protected static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "com.example.i18n.text";
    protected static final String BUNDLE_EXTENSION = "properties";
    protected static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";
    protected static final Control UTF8_CONTROL = new UTF8Control();

    public Text() {
        setParent(ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, 
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale(), UTF8_CONTROL));
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        return parent.getObject(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        return parent.getKeys();
    }

    protected static class UTF8Control extends Control {
        public ResourceBundle newBundle
            (String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
                throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IOException
        {
            // The below code is copied from default Control#newBundle() implementation.
            // Only the PropertyResourceBundle line is changed to read the file as UTF-8.
            String bundleName = toBundleName(baseName, locale);
            String resourceName = toResourceName(bundleName, BUNDLE_EXTENSION);
            ResourceBundle bundle = null;
            InputStream stream = null;
            if (reload) {
                URL url = loader.getResource(resourceName);
                if (url != null) {
                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                    if (connection != null) {
                        connection.setUseCaches(false);
                        stream = connection.getInputStream();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                stream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
            }
            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(new InputStreamReader(stream, CHARSET));
                } finally {
                    stream.close();
                }
            }
            return bundle;
        }
    }
}
```

This expects UTF-8 encoded properties files like `text.properties`, `text_en.properties`, etc in `com.example.i18n` package. No need for native2ascii.

By the way, with the new JSF 2.0 style `<resource-bundle>` declaration in `faces-config.xml`, you don't need `<f:loadBundle>` in the views anymore. All text will be directly available by `#{text}` in all views.

Comment: This is a great tool. Will it be added to OmniFaces some day?

Comment: @Med: I've considered this, but I decided that this is on the edge with "Hacky". Rather use the right editors and build tools such as Eclipse and/or Maven/Ant. E.g., when using Eclipse's builtin properties file editor, UTF-8 will transparently be saved as ISO-8859-1 with unicode codepoints where necessary.

Comment: It is very useful @BalusC. 
Thank you very much.
i have a question here, in xhtml pages we can get value of any key using variable text,  But if we want get it in java code, how can we do that ?

Answer (score 5):

Well, after a deep investigation I have found the solution.

Earlier to java 1.6 `PropertyResourceBundle` had only one constructor which has the following documentation `The property file read with this constructor must be encoded in ISO-8859-1.`
This means that it is possible to use only English text in the resource bundles.

There are two solutions for this issue:

The first one is writing a custom loadBundle component wich will use the correct `ResourceBundle` instantiation method.

The second one (My choice) is using the [Native-to-ASCII](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/native2ascii.html) converter which can be used with maven using the [Native2Ascii maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/native2ascii-maven-plugin/).

Here is the configuration example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>native2ascii</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <src>${basedir}/src/main/resources</src>                
                <dest>${project.build.directory}/native2ascii</dest>
                <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                <includes>**/*.properties</includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with standalone SWT application. This is modified resource loader generated by WindowBuilder. Basic idea - Messages class contain only resources in string fields. So I convert them to UTF8 (if possible) after raw ISO-8859-1 loading.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import org.eclipse.osgi.util.NLS;

public class Messages extends NLS {
private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "org.digimead.tabuddy.desktop.res.messages"; //$NON-NLS-1$
public static String MainWindow_newShell_text;
public static String MainWindow_actionOpenFile_text;
public static String MainWindow_actionCloseFile_text;

// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Constructor
//
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private Messages() {
    // do not instantiate
}

// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Class initialization
//
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
static {
    // load message values from bundle file
    NLS.initializeMessages(BUNDLE_NAME, Messages.class);
    final Field[] fieldArray = Messages.class.getDeclaredFields();
    final int len = fieldArray.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        final Field field = (Field) fieldArray[i];
        if (field.getType() == java.lang.String.class) {
            if (!field.isAccessible())
                field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                final String rawValue = (String) field.get(null);
                field.set(null, new String(rawValue.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),
                        "UTF-8"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // skip field modification
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}