# JSF 2 - Ajax - Locale not updated

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have this bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="langListing")
@ViewScoped
public class LangListing implements Serializable
{
    private List<SelectItem> languages = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    private String language;

    public LangListing() {
       createLangs(); // lazy loading
    }   

    public void createLangs()
    {   
       languages.add(new SelectItem("en", FacesUtil.getResourceBundle().getString("LANG_LABEL_01"))); // English
       languages.add(new SelectItem("fr", FacesUtil.getResourceBundle().getString("LANG_LABEL_02"))); // French
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getLanguages() { 
       return languages;
    }

    public String getLanguage()
    {
       if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale() != null) {
          language = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale().toString();
       } else {
          language = "en";
       }

       return language;
    }

    public void setLanguages(List<SelectItem> languages) {
       this.languages = languages;
    }    

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
       this.language = language;
    }

    public void changeLocale(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale(getLanguage()));
    }
 }
```

I'm calling the bean methods from:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectLang" immediate="true" value="#{langListing.language}">
    <f:ajax listener="#{langListing.changeLocale}" render="@form" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{langListing.languages}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The problem is I can't get the codes to change locale from English to French. Can anyone see the problem? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting it with the value of `getLanguage()` which returns the current `UIViewRoot` locale or otherwise just `en`. It does not return the selected language value.

You need to revise the logic in your bean. Here's a rewrite:

```
@ManagedBean(name="langListing")
@ViewScoped
public class LangListing implements Serializable {
    private List<SelectItem> languages = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    private String language;

    public LangListing() {
       languages.add(new SelectItem("en", FacesUtil.getResourceBundle().getString("LANG_LABEL_01"))); // English
       languages.add(new SelectItem("fr", FacesUtil.getResourceBundle().getString("LANG_LABEL_02"))); // French
       language = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale().toString();
    }   

    public List<SelectItem> getLanguages() { 
       return languages;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
       return language;
    }

    public void setLanguages(List<SelectItem> languages) {
       this.languages = languages;
    }    

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
       this.language = language;
    }

    public void changeLocale(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale(language));
    }
 }
```

Note that there are more potential flaws/holes with this approach. The bean is view scoped instead of session scoped and you don't seem to be using `<f:view>` (since that expects a `Locale`, not `String`). I'd warmly recommend to get yourself through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/jsf-locale-is-set-per-request-not-for-session/4830669#4830669) to align it out.

Comment: @BalusC Ah, I see. You're a genius, man!!! I have another question relating to Ajax and is related to the above issue - can I ask it here or do I have to start a new question?

Comment: You're welcome. For each standalone issue you should ask a new question.

Comment: @BalusC I have two questions regarding the link you supplied above: 1) Can you still use Ajax method or it's redundant because of onchange event? 2) The java.util.Locale class only support a handful of locales and, say, if I want to provide Danish support, how would I use java.util.Locale to do it?

Comment: 1) See your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032455/jsf-2-ajax-form-not-completely-rendered). 2) Just do `new Locale(language)`, exactly as in the linked answer. The absence of a static final constant like `Locale.DANISH` doesn't mean that you cannot use the desired language. Those constants are a leftover of old API and only for top of most used languages in world only.