# JSF 2 - Ajax - Form not completely rendered

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

My Ajax codes for rendering a form using a newly-selected locale are:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectLang" immediate="true" value="#{langListing.language}">
   <f:ajax listener="#{langListing.changeLocale}" render="@form" />
   <f:selectItems value="#{langListing.languages}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

However, since the above codes in in a header file called header.xhtml, the above codes only render the content of header.xhtml when I switch locales between English and French. My index.xhtml structure is as follow:

```
header.xhtml
menu.xhtml
body content with an id of "contentSection"
footer.xhtml
```

How can I render menu.xhtml, the body section and footer.xhtml at the same time as I render header.xhtml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@form` affects the content of parent `<h:form>` only. Use `@all` instead.

```
<f:ajax listener="#{langListing.changeLocale}" render="@all" />
```

See also the description of the `render` attribute in [`<f:ajax>` tag documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html).

However, since changing the locale affects the entire page anyway, you could also consider to fire a synchronous request instead of an ajaxical one. To achieve this, remove the `<f:ajax>` tag, add a `onchange="submit()"` to the dropdown and move the code inside `changeLocale()` into `setLanguage()` method. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/jsf-locale-is-set-per-request-not-for-session/4830669#4830669) for a concrete example.

Comment: I'll have a look at the link and will get back to you.

Comment: That example is of sound programming. It works like a charm. Again, you're the man, BalusC!!!

Comment: I have just recommended several of my programming mates to this site and, of course, **balusc.blogspot.com**. You guys rock!!! Before my mates and I were on Roseindia website but it was crap and ads-laden. Now, I'm feeling happy to be at **stackoverflow**. Thanks so much...

Comment: Truly Roseindia is crap. I am [aware](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/06/what-is-it-with-roseindia.html) about this as well :)