# How to set the current locale in JSF using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsf

Hi I want to change the locale using javascript in the JSF.Can anyone give example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just let JavaScript send a HTTP request in some way (`form.submit()`, `window.location`, ajax, etc) so that JSF is able to do

```
String locale = getItAsRequestParameterOrSomething(); // "en", "en_US", etc
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale(locale));
```

You can find a kickoff example which does that by a dropdown which is submitted by JS in this answer: [Localization in JSF, how to remember selected locale per session instead of per request/view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/jsf-locale-is-set-per-request-not-for-session/4830669#4830669)