# JSF Locale Change Listener not persistent

Tags: jsf, locale

In my WebApp I created a managed Bean that allows me to change the Locale from French to english and vice versa using Event Change Listener.

```
      package beans;

    import java.util.Locale;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LocaleBean {

    private Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return locale.getLanguage();
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        locale = new Locale(language);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
    }

}
```

**and in my template.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="#{localeBean.language}"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <f:view contentType="text/html" locale="#{localeBean.locale}"  id="mescoca">
        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title><ui:insert name="title"></ui:insert></title>
            <h:outputStylesheet name="css/jsfcrud.css"/>
            <!--<f:loadBundle var="bundle" basename="/Bundle"/> -->
        </h:head>

        <h:body style="font-size: small; font-family: Ubuntu,verdana;">
          <h:form>
     <p:panel closable="false" style="float: right;height: 50px;font-size: smaller" >
     <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="text-align: center">
       <h:outputText value="#{bundle.Language}"/>
       <h:selectOneMenu value="#{localeBean.language}"                                 onchange="submit()">
     <f:selectItem itemValue="fr" itemLabel="Français" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="en" itemLabel="English" />
       <f:selectItem itemValue="fr_FR" itemLabel="France"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="en_US" itemLabel="US" />
     </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>
      </p:panel>
```

**The others pages:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="title">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.EditHistoryTitle}"></h:outputText>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="body" >
            <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:form>.....
```

It is working, but the problem is that the language gets back to its first value once I navigate to another page. Otherwise, When I change the language, it only affects the current page and once I move to another page, the localization bundle gets its default value in **faces-config.xml**

What I need is to make the language persistent through the whole session.
Does anyone have a clue plz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your master template in a

```
<f:view locale="#{LanguageBean.localeCode}">
```

#### See also:

- [Localization in JSF, how to remember selected locale per session instead of per request/view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/jsf-locale-is-set-per-request-not-for-session) - contains complete bean/view code example

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the quick response! I reverted to the solution from the given link you mentioned and the problem remains! It is crazy!

Comment: Did you use **exactly the same** code? Even though it's just for testing purposes. You might have made some minor changes or omitted some important parts.

Comment: @BalusC I applied the exact example given! I made no changes!
It might be a problem of refreshing! Maybe my template is not well designed as I am using Primefaces <p:layout to divide my layout into (Top, Left, right, Bottom and center)! I am still not sure that when I click on a menu item, only the center layoutUnit is targeted!
Could it be that the whole layout refreshing on click events makes the language h:selectItems reload its default value? I am trying to check!

Comment: That's not an exact example then. My example didn't use anything of `<p:layout`. I mean, really *only* the code as in my example, just as kickoff test. For example, probably you were actually sending an ajax request while changing the localce. You need to send a non-ajax request or at least re-render the **entire** page.

Comment: @BalusC ok I see what you mean! I am going to apply the example on another plain web app for testing and give the results here! Thank you BalusC

Comment: @BalusC I have just tested on a simple Web app without Faces libraries. And it is working fine! The language lives through the whole session.
But in concerned web app, it is still like it is a request behavior not a session's!
As you said, there might be some ajax calls or events fired and causing the problem! And I guess it is PrimeFaces <p:layout>!
Next step, I think is to user the <p:layout> on my test app, and see if the problem is reproduced! But I recall having it working fine the first time I used <p:layout>! Anyway! If you have any clues, they will be so helpful!

Comment: @BalusC @maple_shaft EDIT: I removed the : 
`<locale-config>
  <default-locale>fr</default-locale> 
 </locale-config>` 
from `faces-config.xml` and now everything is working fine for the Locale persistence. Isn't that weird?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you are setting your Locale in the valueChangeListener you are setting it on the ViewRoot which lives and dies with the current view, and not the session.

You are storing your LocaleCode in the SessionScoped managed bean so you can set the Locale in the ViewRoot for every page and this should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! You mean I need to add <f:view locale="#{LanguageBean.localeCode}" > on my 321 pages? :( –

Comment: Hahaha!!  Thats a big web application ^_^!  I am sure that you can figure out some automated way to do this.

Comment: Yeah indeed it is a big one {\/ô-ô\/} ! Well I tested with a simple web app with no third libraries included!
Same Locale managed bean and same jsf code. and It works fine on all page. There was no need to nest the <f:view locale="#{localeBean.locale}" /> on all pages! As it was already present on the template! Well It really had not to :)
I think there is some issue caused by the <p:layout> of PrimeFaces and it is hard to spot!