# JSF Access Property whos name starts with a number

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I know that this is probably a stupid question, but I am out of luck here. 
I am using a library in Dynamic Web App, with JSF2.0 (primefaces)

I have no problems until I need to access a property of an object defined in the library whos **GETTER FUNCTION** name begins with a number

its as follows

```
class LibraryObject
{
 private String PerfectlyNamedVariable;
 public String get32BitAddress(){ return this.PerfectlyNamedVariable; }
}
```

now to access this "PerfectlyNamedVariable" String property (which I dont know what the naming is, all I can see is the public getter function) in JSF xhtml, usually I would go about like this

say the instances of LibraryObject are in a list in a Bean and the JSF is rendering a table with

```
<p:dataTable value="#{MyBean.LibraryObjectList}"  var="instance" >
   <p:column headerText="32 Bit Address">
     <h:outputText value="#{instance.32BitAddress}" />
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

and had the **GETTER FUNCTION** been named starting with anything but a number it would have been no issue,but in this case I get this error

```
Failed to parse the expression [#{instance.32BitAddress}]
```

I really cant change the source code of the library to adjust the naming, and apparently my research skills are not up to the standard to find that on my own today. **So How can I access a property whos name starts with a number ?**

Thank you very much

Comment: How java is allowing you to create variable name that starts with number ? it is not possible. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html. A valid java variable name can start with only letters, underscore or dollar

Comment: Well My Mistake, your absolutely correct. But that is in the library which I cannot see, and probably as you say, the actual variable doesnt start with a number. Nonetheless, genius who made the getter function called it get32BitAddress(), which is now to be accessed as Instance.32BitAddress in JSF which miserably fails to parse and thats where I am stuck

Comment: Just edited the question, maybe it would make more sense to you now

Comment: Pleae refer the answre for [Calling methods from JSF page doubts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594920/calling-methods-from-jsf-page-doubts?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following expression for accessing such fields -

```
<h:outputText value="${instance.get32BitAddress()}" />
```

Using this approach, you can only get the value. You can not set. Since you are using this value in `<h:outputText>` so it would not be a problem while submitting form.