# javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to find method xyz with [0] parameters - Value expression vs method expression

Tags: el, jsf-2.2

So i am a bit confused by the use of value expressions and method expressions in jsf. My understanding of the two terms is that:

- if its a property of a bean with getter and setter function, it would be called a value expression.
- if its a regular method of a class, not a property (hence no getter or setters) than its called a method expression.

Please correct me if that is wrong.

Now i am confused how the two can be used in a jsf page.

My bean has a method like:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class myBean implements Serializable {

/*Some bean properties here*/ 

private Set<String> getFilterTerms() {

        /*Some logic here*/

        return filterTerms;
    }
}
```

I am trying to render a jsf page panelGroup, depending on the size of the set returned by the above function.

```
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.getFilterTerms().size() > 0}" layout="block" style="margin-top:60px">

  //Display some html elements here

 </h:panelGroup>
```

i get the following error with this code.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to find method [getFilterTerms] with [0] parameters.
```

1. Is it possible to use a method expression the way i have in a
   rendered attribute?
2. If not, do i have to make a bean attribute of
   filterterms and than implement the code in getters and setters?

My question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594920/calling-methods-from-jsf-page-doubts) but in the link its a static method while mine is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the method `getFilterTerms` to be private.

Comment: Making it public now gives the following error:
javax.servlet.ServletException: /researcher/index.xhtml @61,119 rendered="#{researcherQueriesBean.getFilterTerms.size() > 0}": Property 'getFilterTerms' not found on type myPackage.myBean

Answer (score 0):

Your EL should not use the "get" or the brackets "()" when referring to a property

use the following instead:

```
#{myBean.filterTerms.size() > 0}
```

note the lowercase "f"