# Set decimal separator when using f:convertNumber

Tags: jsf, numbers, decimal, converters, separator

I want to know how to set the default decimal separator on my JSF application. I have some `<h:inputText>` that I need to format as money, with 2 decimals. Right now the decimal separator used by default is the comma `,` and this gives me an error when I do some operations on save. I don't know if I can set the decimal separator to be used everytime that I use `<f:convertNumber>` tag.

I tried to use this:

```
<f:convertNumber pattern="########0.00" groupingUsed="false" />
```

but it still sets the comma as decimal separator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default decimal separator depends on the locale used. You can set it in 2 ways:

1. On a per-view basis by the `locale` attribute of the [`<f:view>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/view.html) tag:

   ```html
    <f:view locale="#{bean.locale}">
   ```
2. On a per-converter basis by the `locale` attribute of the [`<f:convertNumber>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/convertNumber.html) tag:

   ```html
    <f:convertNumber locale="#{bean.locale}" />
   ```

It's unclear what locale you're targeting, but the use of `.` as fraction separator is typical for US dollars with a locale of `en-US`, for example. So you need to set it as such:

```html
<f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" locale="en-US" />
```

It can also be obtained from a [`java.util.Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) bean property.

```html
<f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" locale="#{bean.locale}" />
```

Note that I used `type="currency"`, that's more self-documenting.

#### See also:

- [Does <f:convertNumber> use the right number separator when using patterns to format currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765009/does-fconvertnumber-use-the-right-number-separator-when-using-patterns-to-for/)
- [Localization in JSF, how to remember selected locale per session instead of per request/view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/localization-in-jsf-how-to-remember-selected-locale-per-session-instead-of-per)

Comment: There is a difference between the input format and the display format. In a french local the decimal separator is the comma. But if a user uses the numeric keypad, he will use the dot separator and this triggers an error. I find it hard to explain that he shouldn't use the numeric keypad.

Comment: @grigouille: just set a different locale on input or create a custom converter.