# Change "f:convertNumber" decimal separator symbol

Tags: jsf

Can anyone tell me  how i can replace the "comma" with "dot" as thousand separator on `f:convertNumber`?

JSF 2.2
Primefaces 3.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize number format with locale attribute.
To have dot as thousand separator you can use "es_PE" locale.
See all locale formats here:
[f:convertNumber remove comma as thousand separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835888/fconvertnumber-remove-comma-as-thousand-separator)