# How can I use a thousands delimiter?

Tags: jsf, delimiter

How can i put a thousands delimiter in JSF for a unspecified number? for ex for 3000 or x'xxx? I read about pattern recognition, but don't fully understand it. I dont have a specific number, rather it can change. But sth with xxxx and it should be x'xxx.

Comment: I tried this, but with me there commes pattern exception, I tried x'xxx  <f:convertNumber pattern="x'xxx" />

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy A comma is not an apostrophe.

Comment: I need to have the separator on top

Comment: That's called an [apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe). You basically want a Swiss German localized number format.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835888/fconvertnumber-remove-comma-as-thousand-separator

Comment: It seems to be Swiss regardless the language (German, French or Italian). Any Swiss format will do :-)

Comment: ok thaxs I will try this with convertnumber pattern

Comment: You don't need a pattern, just set the locale