# Display amount in format $###,###,###.## using f:convertNumber

Tags: jsf, number-formatting

I would like to display the amount in `$12,050,999.00` format.

I tried as follows:

```
<h:outputText value="#{sampleBean.Amount}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###" currencySymbol="$" type="currency"/>
</h:outputText>
```

However, it didn't display the amount in the desired format. I got `12,050,999` instead.

The desired format is shown in the below image:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `pattern` overrides `type`. And guess what, your `pattern` is wrong. Just get rid of it.

Comment: So,what pattern should i use @BalusC

Comment: As said, just get rid of it. `pattern` and `type` are mutually exclusive. When both are specified, `pattern` overrides `type`. Your desired currency pattern is already implicitly set by `type="currency"`.

Comment: So, if i use <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###" currencySymbol="$"/> it will work is what u r saying

Comment: @BalusC if i am using this `<f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" type="currency"/  `then it is displaying in the format of `$10000000.00` but i am in need to display as `$100,000,00.00` format which is not happening even if i remove any one among `pattern` and `type` which are mutual exclusive

Comment: Apparently your locale is not US. Set it as `locale="en_US"` in either `<f:view>` or `<f:convertNumber>`.

Comment: try experimenting with a `locale=""` attribute.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your `pattern` is wrong for a currency. You should be using `pattern="¤#,##0.00"`.

```
<f:convertNumber pattern="¤#,##0.00" currencySymbol="$" />
```

However, there's more at matter: in your original code you also specified the `type` attribute, which is correct, but this is mutually exclusive with the `pattern` attribute whereby the `pattern` attribute gets precedence.

You should actually be omitting the `pattern` attribute and stick to the `type` attribute.

```
<f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" />
```

Note that this uses the locale as available by `UIViewRoot#getLocale()` which is expected to be an English/US based locale in order to get the right final format for the USD currency. You'd like to explicitly specify it in either the `<f:view>`:

```
<f:view locale="en_US">
```

or in the `locale` attribute of the `<f:convertNumber>`:

```
<f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" locale="en_US" />
```

#### See also:

- [Does <f:convertNumber> use the right number separator when using patterns to format currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765009/does-fconvertnumber-use-the-right-number-separator-when-using-patterns-to-for/)

Comment: I am trying the same with InputText "<pe:inputNumber id="AmtField" value="#{myController.amtVlaue}" symbol="$" /> " but i am not able to solve the [issue with paste](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=35104)

Comment: [Added a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760853/unable-to-paste-the-content-in-primefaces-extension-peinputnumber-using-mouse)