# p:inputText decimal separator

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i want a comma decimal separator when user press decimal key, but after many test, not work any.
number is String type why on db is definited string
tried

```
<p:inputText value="#{testController.number}">
    <f:convertNumber  locale="it"/>
</p:inputText>
```

tried

```
<default-locale>it_IT</default-locale>
```

in faces-config
but any success.

Suggest?

Comment: `<f:convertNumber pattern="000,000,00" /> ?

Comment: @Mahendran: OP is storing numbers as strings instead of as numbers. The `<f:convertNumber>` wil in no way work. End of story. Nonetheless, your suggestion is incorrect. Here's some food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19765009

Comment: @BalusC missed it. OP > i want a comma decimal separator when user press decimal key
You can try with javascript.
    <p:inputText value="#{testController.number}" onkeyup="myFunc()"> check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923089/can-i-conditionally-change-the-character-entered-into-an-input-on-keypress/3923320#3923320

Comment: @BalusC Is it the locale attribute the give away he is using String ?

Comment: @BalusC is an old erp third party and I can not change

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<p:inputNumber>` it automatically generates commas for your integers.