# How to export numbers which has commas from Primefaces datatable with out green mark in Excel

Tags: excel, primefaces, export

How to export numbers which has commas from Primefaces datatable  with out green mark in Excel sheet. Below is my sample code which i am using in the datatable.

The below code will print a number like 1,231,834 which will export to Excel sheet

```
<h:outputText value="#{v.viewCountsRecorded}" >
        <f:convertNumber/> 
 </h:outputText>
```

But in Excel the cell has a green mark which has this number.
I am looking for a answer how to export this number to excel with out getting that green mark. Can some one help me.

Answer (score 0):

If they are all integers you can use `<f:convertNumber groupingUsed="false"/>`.

If they are not all integers you have several options as described by BalusC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856152/set-decimal-separator-when-formatting-hintputtext).