# jsf locales 1 step behind, with htmlpanelgrid (not updated because auf restore view)

Tags: jsf, view, restore

i am using htmlpanelgrid with  to build my dynamic navigation.
The Page contains 3 commandlinks for changing the language (with an image).
If i hit the image (commandlink) to change the language, the navigation is always 1 step behind with the new language.

The navigation become build on Phase 1 (restore view) and the new language is set on Phase 5.
Means, if i change the language the htmlpanelgrid is build with the old language before the new value is set.
how to get rid of that ?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the locale explicitly on the `UIViewRoot` during the action method.

```
public void changeLocaleAction() {
    locale = new Locale(language);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
}
```

Otherwise you need to send a redirect back to the same view.

```
public String changeLocaleAction() {
    locale = new Locale(language);
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

#### See also:

- [Localization in JSF, how to remember selected locale per session instead of per request/view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/jsf-locale-is-set-per-request-not-for-session/4830669#4830669)

Comment: the locale is stored in a session Bean, and the trick with:      return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true"; did it, thanks again! and have a nice day