# Implementing I18N in JSF

Tags: jsf, internationalization

I'd like to set the specific user locale when he login, in my JSF app.

To do this I get the user locale from his properties and set user locale via

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(userLocale);
```

during login fase on successful login.

My problem is that when I show messages to the user in subsequent fases during the user session the locale I get via

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (context != null && context.getViewRoot() != null) {
        locale = context.getViewRoot().getLocale();
        ...
```

is always the default locale.

I've no other points in my code where I set locale, so I can't figure out why this happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4830588/870122

Comment: It is because ViewRoot is request-scoped, so it will change with each new HTTP request. You'll need to create some session-scoped bean and store Locale there.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically only setting the locale for the **current** view, the login page. You need to remember the user locale in the session scope and set it in all subsequent views in the same session as well.

You can do that by making `userLocale` a property of some session scoped bean (perhaps just the logged-in user itself?) and referencing it as `<f:view locale>` in your master template.

```
<f:view locale="#{user.locale}">
```

This will implicitly perform `viewRoot.setLocale(user.getLocale())` for every single view.

#### See also:

- [Localization in JSF, how to remember selected locale per session instead of per request/view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/jsf-locale-is-set-per-request-not-for-session/)

Answer (score 0):

You should say something more in what why do you collect from request information about user preffered local but lets say that you get it from header `accept-language`

Then, as JSF specification says:

> The UIViewRoot’s Locale is determined and set by the ViewHandler during the execution of the
> ViewHandler’s createView() method. This method must cause the active Locale to be
> determined by looking at the user’s preferences combined with the application’s stated supported locales.

So one thing is to set Locale in ViewRoot and to collect Locale from request header and another thing is to proper set supported locales in your config file.

In other part of specification you can read (see `ViewHandler calculateLocale` method):

> Method Application.getSupportedLocales() defines what locales this JSF application is capable of supporting. This method should match such sources of data up and return the Locale object that is the best choice for rendering the current application to the current user.

Why is it going in such way? Because you cannot send response to user with locale preffered by user if your apps isn't supported to send respond with that locale.
Now all you have to do (I hope so) is to configure your `faces-config.xml` in `WEB-INF` directory like this (also copied from JSF Specification):

```
<faces-config>
  <application>
    <locale-config>
      <default-locale>en</default-locale>
      <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
      <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
      <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
//    ...
    </locale-config>
  </application>
</faces-config>
```