# Internalization using view handler displays blank page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

```
public class LocaleViewHandler extends ViewHandler{

    private final ViewHandler base;

    public LocaleViewHandler(ViewHandler base){
        super();
        this.base = base;
    }
    @Override
    public Locale calculateLocale(FacesContext context) {
          Locale locale;
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
          .getSession(false);
      if (session != null) {
          //Return the locale saved by the managed bean earlier
          locale = (Locale) session.getAttribute("locale");
          if (locale == null) {
              locale= new Locale("en");

           }
          return locale;
      }
     return base.calculateLocale(context);

    }

    @Override
    public String calculateRenderKitId(FacesContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return base.calculateRenderKitId(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public UIViewRoot createView(FacesContext arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return base.createView(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public String getActionURL(FacesContext arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return base.getActionURL(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public String getResourceURL(FacesContext arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return base.getResourceURL(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderView(FacesContext arg0, UIViewRoot arg1)
            throws IOException, FacesException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        base.renderView(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public UIViewRoot restoreView(FacesContext arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return base.restoreView(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeState(FacesContext arg0) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        base.writeState(arg0);
    }

    public ViewHandler getBase() {
        return base;
    }


}
```

I am trying working on internalization example, I wrote the view handler as shown above. I have two locale English and french. But after writing this handler. There is no error on console but it displays blank white page.What could be done to see the view..

Answer (score 3):

You should extend [`ViewHandlerWrapper`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandlerWrapper.html) instead of writing your own `ViewHandler`.

```
public class LocaleViewHandler extends ViewHandlerWrapper {

    private ViewHandler wrapped;

    public LocaleViewHandler(ViewHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public Locale calculateLocale(FacesContext context) {
        // Do your thing here.
    }

}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this isn't entirely the right approach. You should just use

```
<f:view locale="#{localeBean.locale}">
```

instead. See also [Localization in JSF, how to remember selected locale per session instead of per request/view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/jsf-locale-is-set-per-request-not-for-session/4830669#4830669).