# Required Some Best practices to detect the locale of a user using jsf2 + spring web flow

Tags: spring, jsf-2, locale, spring-webflow

I am just trying to figure out some good approches to detect the locale.

The approach I am following is :

1-One language Bean with the below code

```
<code>
if(!classUtil.isNullObject(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())){
            return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestLocale();
        }
        return selectedLanguage;//Return default language in case its not possible to detect the language
</code>
```

2- creating bean definition inside parent-flow

```
<code><var name="languageBean" class="com.decitysearch.classified.LanguageBean"/></code>
```

3- using the same in the xhtml

```
<code>
<f:view locale="#{languageBean.findDefaultLocale}">
<f:loadBundle var="messageResource" basename="MessageResource_en"/>   
</code>
```

My questions here it goes like:
1-can't we make the bean entry inside spring-context rather than flow bean as I tried with spring-context but getting some scope exceptions.
2-Is there any good approaches to detect the locale

your thought process is highly appreciated.

Comment: I have no utter idea how Spring/Webflow plays a role, so I won't go in detail, but for the canonical JSF approach, head to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4830669. Note that `UIViewRoot#getLocale()` already defaults to request locale and thus you're essentially unnecessarily taking over some "under the covers" work in #1.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Spring**, declare these beans and call URL with parameter "locale=xx" to change locale:

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="es" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```