# execute the method before load JSF Page

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, localization, facelets

I am retrieving the user's locale from the database. Whenever user is login then page should display on that perticular language. So for this i am using below code in the JSF

```
    <f:metadata>
       <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{language.preferredLocale}"/>
    </f:metadata>
    <ui:define name="content_pane">
    <f:view locale="#{language.localeCode}"/>
    </ui:define>

    //language bean code is
    public void preferredLocale(ComponentSystemEvent e){
        // code to retrieve locale for particular user              
    }
```

But the above code is not working to set the locale on the page onload. is there anyother way i can set the locale on the page load?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed not the right way. It's too late then. You need to make sure that `<f:view locale>` is already set right.

There are several ways to achieve this anyway, depending on your current application design. The simplest one would probably be the following:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public void LoginBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{localeBean}")
    private LocaleBean localeBean;

    public void submit() {
        User user = userService.find(username, password);

        if (user != null) {
            localeBean.setLanguage(user.getPreferences().getLanguage());
            // ...
        }

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to add language on the JSF page?

Comment: Set it as `<f:view locale>`. See for another example also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/jsf-locale-is-set-per-request-not-for-session/4830669#4830669

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<f:view beforePhase=#{bean.viewBeforePhase} >
```