# How to change the locale for one view in jsf?

Tags: jsf, locale

there is a way to change the locale for especific view in jsf? 
i can try the locale via faces-config.xml, but i just wanna a specific view.

```
faces-config version="1.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">

    <application>
        <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>es</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>ca</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the locale on a *per-view basis* by nesting your content in a [`<f:view>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/) tag that has one of its attributes, `locale`, for exactly this purpose:

```
<f:view locale="#{localeBean.selectedlocale}">
```

For more information consult [Localization in JSF, how to remember selected locale per session instead of per request/view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/jsf-locale-is-set-per-request-not-for-session).