# SEAM / Java EE - Set Locale From Domain

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, seam, seam2

I have a SEAM 2.2.2 App running on JBoss AS6

The App is setup with a number of languages

In the JBoss deploy directory /jbossweb.sar/server.xml I have mapped a number of different domains using the following Host entries

```
<Host name="myApp">  
  <Alias>www.myapp.com</Alias>  
  <Alias>myapp.com</Alias>  
  <Alias>www.myapp.sv</Alias>  
  <Alias>myapp.sv</Alias>  
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"  
  prefix="processor" suffix=".log" pattern="common"  
  directory="${jboss.server.home.dir}/log"/>  
  <Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve"  
  cachedConnectionManagerObjectName="jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager"  
  transactionManagerObjectName="jboss:service=TransactionManager" ></Valve>  
</Host>
```

We need to be able to ensure that all visitors who land on www.myapp.sv have the default language set to swedish even if their browser defaults to english

What would be the best way to achieve this? My initial guess would be to check which locale is set when the page is requested then use Seam's localeSelector to override the default set by the browser but this seems like a bit of a hack and potentially wasteful as the resource bundles would be loaded then reloaded?

Is there any way to 'intercept' the initial locale selection and override it with one based on the domain extension?

Thanks

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/4830588/1065197

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved this by creating a Session scoped bean and putting requested language as a query parameter, then using pages.xml action which are fired before page in rendered to set current locale

Answer (score 0):

Make a startup LocaleBean and set the desired locale.

Thus something like this:

```
@Startup
@Scope(APPLICATION)
@Name("LocaleBean")
public class LocaleBean {         

     @Create
     public void init() {
         FacesContext.instance().getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale("SV"));
     }
}
```

Comment: this needs to be done on a 'per session' basis, using the application scope would only set the locale once when the app is deployed