# <default-locale> does not seem to work, instead the <supported-locale> is being used

Tags: jsf-2, localization

i wanted to set the default location of my jsf web project to english, so
i did the following:

faces-config.xml

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en_EN</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>de_DE</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>de.hof.tschuwwa.resources.messages</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

i have a package in my src folder `de.hof.tschuwwa.resources` and inside
of that package i have two property files:

```
messages_de_DE.properties
messages_en_EN.properties
```

and i tested it in a small xhtml file:

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/templates/master.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="header">
            <h:form>
                <h:commandButton action="#{navigationService.toLogin}" value="#{msg['login']}" />
                <h:commandButton action="#{navigationService.toRegister}" value="#{msg['register']}" />
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>            
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

When i start my application it shows the german values and not 
the english values. i wanted the default language to be english.

How can i set my default language? The faces-config.xml default-locale
does not seem to work.

Also i need to know how i can change my localization. i wrote this small
service:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LanguageService implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void changeLanguage(String language) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale(language));
    }
}
```

and tried out with the following buttons inside a form:

```
<p:commandButton id="english" value="English" action="#{languageService.changeLanguage('en')}" immediate="true" />
<p:commandButton id="german" value="Deutsch" action="#{languageService.changeLanguage('de')}" immediate="true" />
```

but nothing happened when i used them.

Comment: Is your browser setting the default locale to DE?

Comment: Even if i change my browsers default local to english my web app loads all german messages

Comment: Are you sure en_EN locale exists at all? I'm 90% sure everything will work fine when using en_US or en_GB instead. And renaming properties files of course.

Answer (score 28):

```
<default-locale>en_EN</default-locale>
```

First of all, you've there a mistake in the locale identifier `en_EN`. The first two lowercase characters represent the [ISO 693-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) language code. It is optional and only required whenever the country code is present. The last two uppercased characters represent the [ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) country code. It is optional and often only used to distinguish between country-specific language dialects, like [American English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_English) (`en_US`) and [British English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_English) (`en_GB`). There's no such country like "England", so `en_EN` is definitely invalid. You most likely want to use `en` or perhaps `en_US` here.

Thus, so

```
<default-locale>en</default-locale>
```

with an appropriate `messages_en.properties` file.

---

> *How can i set my default language? The faces-config.xml default-locale does not seem to work.*

The `<default-locale>` is only used when the client didn't supply the locale by itself in flavor of the `Accept-Language` HTTP request header, or supplied one which isn't supported by the application as definied in `<supported-locale>`. A lot of (sane) clients actually set the `Accept-Language` header. With a HTTP traffic monitor you can see them.

[image]

*(the screen says: `en-US` is the first preference (with a default "weight" of 1), the `en` is the second preference with a "weight" of 0.8, the `nl` is the third preference with a "weight" of 0.6; in Chrome you can change this in `chrome://settings/languages` by adding/removing/reordering languages)*.

If you want to prevent this and want to force the "default" locale for some unclear reason, then you'd need to explicitly set the `<f:view locale>` to the desired "default" locale (note: you're thus actually overriding client's preferred locale as configured in its program — the webbrowser).

E.g.:

```
<f:view locale="#{languageService.language}">
```

*(just put in master template, wrapping the `<h:head>` and `<h:body>`)*

with this new property in your backing bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LanguageService implements Serializable {

    private Locale locale;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getDefaultLocale();
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

> *Also i need to know how i can change my localization.*

Your mistake in this particular example is that you're not updating the view after invoking the action. You need to add `update="@all"` to the command buttons. But there's another mistake: you're not remembering the locale for subsequent requests. It would fall back to the "default" locale again. You need to set the `<f:view locale>` with this property. This is already answered in detail before: [Localization in JSF, how to remember selected locale per session instead of per request/view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/jsf-locale-is-set-per-request-not-for-session).

Comment: If the user enters some information in the form and then changes the language with the buttons "english" or "german", is there a way to keep the information the user had already entered?