# Something basic about Java pointers and changing locale in JSF application

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I just tried to implement JSF Internationalization based on this article - "[Internationalization in JSF with UTF-8 encoded properties files](http://jdevelopment.nl/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/)" and found something weird. Is it right way to change locale by using code in this bean?

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LocaleBean {

    private Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return locale.getLanguage();
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.locale = new Locale(language);
    }

}
```

As I understand Java `private Locale locale` must be pointer to actual Locale object from viewRoot object but this method didn't work at me. Instead, when I changed `setLanguage(String language)` method to this

```
public void setLanguage(String language) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale(language));
    }
```

it began to work. Now I wonder where is mistake? What's wrong with @BulusC code? Maybe I did something wrong, maybe I forget something?
When I debugged I seen that `private Locale locale` and locale object from viewRoot are different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the code was missing the line you've posted. From this question: [Localization in JSF, how to remember selected locale per session instead of per request/view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4830588/1065197), answered by BalusC, you can check the code for `setLanguage` (code taken from BalusC's answer, not mine):

```
public void setLanguage(String language) {
    locale = new Locale(language);
    //this is the line you added
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but now I wonder why BalusC didn't change him code in article :( Is it so difficult :(

Comment: @Anatoly what worries me more is how other people posted that worked fine =\