# JSF render dir="rtl" when language is arabic

Tags: jsf, localization, dir, conditional-rendering

I want to render the text direction rtl (Right-To-Left) in an inputText when the browser's Accept-Language is arabic in my JSF application. When Accept-Language is english the text introduced by the user would be dir="ltr" (Left-To-Right). How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The client's `Accept-Language` is indirectly available via [`UIViewRoot#getLocale()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getLocale()). The `UIViewRoot` is in turn in EL available as `#{view}`. So, this should do:

```
<h:inputText ... dir="#{view.locale.language eq 'ar' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'}" />
```

Note that the `dir` is also supported on all other components and HTML elements, such as `<h:form>` and even `<html>`.

```
<html ... dir="#{view.locale.language eq 'ar' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'}">
```

It would be applied on all its children unless overridden by a differently set `dir`. That would save you from repeating the very same attribute over all child components/elements.

Also note that the JSF will only accept locales which are explicitly registered in `<locale-config>` in `faces-config.xml`. So if you don't already have `ar` in there, then the above wouldn't work irrespective of `Accept-Language` header.

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>ar</supported-locale>
        ...
    </locale-config>
</application>
```

Move if necessary the logic to a managed bean so that you can end up like below:

```
<h:inputText ... dir="#{localeManager.dir}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Localization in JSF, how to remember selected locale per session instead of per request/view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/jsf-locale-is-set-per-request-view-not-for-session)