# Showing converter / validator messages in different languages without rewriting them by creating different message bundles

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

Could you please tell me, if we can use PrimeFaces validators in different languages without rewriting all messages using a <s>resource-bundle</s> message bundle? In other words does PrimeFaces have a library of predefined validation messages.

For example, I would like to have messages below in French, Italic... without rewriting them.

[image: example in picture]

Comment: No. Are these even PrimeFaces validators, not just JSF or JSR 303 bean annotations?

Comment: PrimeFaces defines only a few messages in its message bundle related to `<p:captcha>`, `<p:password>` and `<p:tree>` with the default locale only. The rest of the validations belong to standard JSF which has a few predefined locales but besides locales, you will want to show user-friendly messages. In that case, there is no way other than overriding default converter / validator messages by creating message bundles of your own.

Comment: Your concrete problem is hard to understand. Standard validator messages are already localized. Perhaps your actual problem is one step before: do you know how to set the locale of a JSF view? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/localization-in-jsf-how-to-remember-selected-locale-per-session-instead-of-per