# Primefaces calendar locale separates date by '/' instead of '.'

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, calendar

**Prerequisites:**
- JSF 2.1
- Primefaces 5.2
- Glassfish 3.1

**Problem:**
When using the following locale for my calendars, they separate the displayed date by a slash '/' instead of a dot '.'. So 1.1.2016 turns into 1/1/2016. If i remove the locale flag from my calendar, it separates with dots again.

**Question:**
How do i make my locale split the date with dot instead of slash?

**My locale**
My locale is basically the en_US locale without the messages from this website: **https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Locales**

```
PrimeFaces.locales ['ps'] = {
closeText: 'Close',
prevText: 'Previous',
nextText: 'Next',
monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ],
monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ],
dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
dayNamesShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Tue', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W ', 'T', 'F ', 'S'],
weekHeader: 'Week',
firstDay: 1,
isRTL: false,
showMonthAfterYear: false,
yearSuffix:'',
timeOnlyTitle: 'Only Time',
timeText: 'Time',
hourText: 'Time',
minuteText: 'Minute',
secondText: 'Second',
currentText: 'Current Date',
ampm: false,
month: 'Month',
week: 'week',
day: 'Day',
allDayText: 'All Day',
};
```

Comment: Does your `<p:calendar` have a `pattern` attribute set? If not, try to set a pattern first.

Comment: or most likely the default separator for 'ps' is a slash?

Comment: Not sure about Java, but in Windows (Vista) it is: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx?submitted=0463&OS=Windows%20Vista

Comment: But, why are you using the `ps` locale to have English values!?

Comment: [Localization in JSF, how to remember selected locale per session instead of per request/view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/localization-in-jsf-how-to-remember-selected-locale-per-session-instead-of-per)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Primefaces `calendar` there is an attribute called `pattern`, you can use it to change the pattern of dates, for exemple `<p:calendar pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" />` this will show `12.10.2016 15:42`, you can change the pattern to separate the date however you like using dots, slach or any character. There no problem using the two attributes `locale` and `pattern` at the same time, it works fine for me.