# How does dataLocale attribute work in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Helo; I have checked the Manual of PrimeFaces11 and googled but I can't find any example of how to use that attribute. ChatGPT said "es-MX" and "en-US" but none seem to work. Any ideas? :'(

I'm expecting the titles like "Ascending" to be "Ascendente" (in spanish) (i listed what i have tried already)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataLocale` is used "in features such as filtering and sorting" (see [`DataTable` documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/datatable)). So it is not used to translate UI texts. For that please refer to the [localization documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/core/localization). [Spanish](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/11.0.0/primefaces/src/main/resources/org/primefaces/Messages_es.properties) is supported out of the box. Just set the correct locale in your view.

See also:

- [Localization in JSF, how to remember selected locale per session instead of per request/view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588/localization-in-jsf-how-to-remember-selected-locale-per-session-instead-of-per)