# hibernate validator + jsf 2.0: ValidationMessages.properties in UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, jsf-2, hibernate-validator

I have a problem with displaying custom ValidationMessages of Hibernate Validator in UTF-8.

For common jsf messages I followed this advice: [i18n with UTF-8 encoded properties files in JSF 2.0 appliaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645491/i18n-with-utf-8-encoded-properties-files-in-jsf-2-0-appliaction) - I created class Text and used it in faces-config.xml. This is working properly.

But this approach is not working with ValidationMessages; special characters are not displayed in UTF-8.

Could anyone give me some advice about this? Thank you very much

Comment: Actually I manage to solve this with the same solution as for jsf messages. The same class with "ValidationMessages" bundle name can be used and added to faces-config.xml as new <resource-bundle /> element.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved in the same way. Hibernate validator has configuration file in META-INF/validation.xml

Example for **validation.xml**

```
<validation-config xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration">
    <message-interpolator>com.mycompany.validation.utf8.UTF8ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator</message-interpolator>
</validation-config>
```

Implementation for **UTF8ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator**

```
public class UTF8ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator extends ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator {

    public UTF8ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator() {
        super(new UTF8ResourceBundleLocator(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.USER_VALIDATION_MESSAGES));
    }
}
```

Implementation for **UTF8ResourceBundleLocator** (clone of PlatformResourceBundleLocator class with small fix)

```
public class UTF8ResourceBundleLocator implements ResourceBundleLocator {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UTF8ResourceBundleLocator.class);

    protected static final ResourceBundle.Control UTF8_CONTROL = new UTF8Control();

    private final String bundleName;

    public UTF8ResourceBundleLocator(String bundleName) {
        this.bundleName = bundleName;
    }


    /**
     * Search current thread classloader for the resource bundle. If not found,
     * search validator (this) classloader.
     *
     * @param locale The locale of the bundle to load.
     * @return the resource bundle or <code>null</code> if none is found.
     */
    @Override
    public ResourceBundle getResourceBundle(Locale locale) {
        ResourceBundle rb = null;
        ClassLoader classLoader = GetClassLoader.fromContext();
        if (classLoader != null) {
            rb = loadBundle(
                    classLoader, locale, bundleName
                            + " not found by thread local classloader"
            );
        }
        if (rb == null) {
            classLoader = GetClassLoader.fromClass(PlatformResourceBundleLocator.class);
            rb = loadBundle(
                    classLoader, locale, bundleName
                            + " not found by validator classloader"
            );
        }

        return rb;
    }

    private ResourceBundle loadBundle(ClassLoader classLoader, Locale locale, String message) {
        ResourceBundle rb = null;
        try {
            rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
                    bundleName, locale,
                    classLoader, UTF8_CONTROL
            );
        } catch (MissingResourceException ignored) {
            logger.trace(message);
        }
        return rb;
    }

    private static class GetClassLoader implements PrivilegedAction<ClassLoader> {
        private final Class<?> clazz;

        private static ClassLoader fromContext() {
            final GetClassLoader action = new GetClassLoader(null);
            if (System.getSecurityManager() != null) {
                return AccessController.doPrivileged(action);
            } else {
                return action.run();
            }
        }

        private static ClassLoader fromClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            if (clazz == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class is null");
            }
            final GetClassLoader action = new GetClassLoader(clazz);
            if (System.getSecurityManager() != null) {
                return AccessController.doPrivileged(action);
            } else {
                return action.run();
            }
        }

        private GetClassLoader(Class<?> clazz) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        @Override
        public ClassLoader run() {
            if (clazz != null) {
                return clazz.getClassLoader();
            } else {
                return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where **UTF8Control** class is the class from [i18n with UTF-8 encoded properties files in JSF 2.0 appliaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645491/i18n-with-utf-8-encoded-properties-files-in-jsf-2-0-appliaction)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same Resource-Bundle like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3646601/5072526, you can do this:

Modify the ResourceBundle from that answer, so you have an additional Constructor, that takes a locale:

```
public I18NUtf8RessourceBundle(Locale locale) {
    setParent(ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, 
            locale, UTF8_CONTROL));
}
```

Then create a Class `ValidationMessages` in the default package:

```
public class ValidationMessages extends I18NUtf8RessourceBundle{
   public ValidationMessages() {
        super(null);
    }
}
```

Then make the same Class with a specific Locale (_en, _de, etc.):

```
public class ValidationMessages_en extends I18NUtf8RessourceBundle{
    public ValidationMessages_en() {
        super(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
}
```

Do the same for all your Languages and pass a different Locale each time:

With that, it works, you can even have the same File for the Validation Messages as for the normal translations!