# Spring uses wrong codification for customized validation messages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, utf-8, internationalization, bean-validation

I have a Spring form wih some validations and all the personalized messeges from javax.validation.constraints appears to use the wrong encoding.

Lets take this as an example:

```
@NumberFormat(style=Style.NUMBER) 
@NotNull 
private BigDecimal maintenanceCosts;
```

With applicationContext.xml file containing

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:messages</value>
            <value>classpath:ValidationMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
```

And a ValidationMessage_en.properties encoded in UTF-8 and marked so (in Eclipse with right click, properties) with the text:

> javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=This field can't be empty

I want to show thouse messages in localized strings with the right codification so I added an UTF-8 file ValidationMessages_ru.properties with:

> javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=**Это поле не может быть
>   пустым**

But the message shows this message: 
**Ð­Ñ‚Ð¾ Ð¿Ð¾Ð»Ðµ Ð½Ðµ Ð¼Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÑ‚ Ð±Ñ‹Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð¿ÑƒÑÑ‚Ñ‹Ð¼**

On the other hand I has able to customize the spring managed error messages with the right encoding. But JSR303 texts seems to behave differently.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the properties file is in UTF-8 and Eclipse is not autosilly encoding non-ASCII characters? Did you check the file in a normal text editor?

Comment: I used notepad++ to do it

Comment: Well, please try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20912549/2217862) configuration. It may not be related with your issue, but just to be sure that it’s not a configuration problem.  What version of Spring and Hibernate Validator are you using?

Comment: Spring version is 3.2.3.RELEASE
Hibernate validator is 4.2.0.Final

Comment: Oki, did you try the linked configuration? If it did not work, then try to upgrade Hibernate Validator to 4.3.1.Final.

Comment: I have tried it and after making the change I only see the default mesage.  I will try the upgrade

Comment: by the way see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421790/hibernate-validator-jsf-2-0-validationmessages-properties-in-utf-8

May be the problem is that I am not familiar at all with Java Server Faces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that it was much more elegant to get rid of the ValidationMessages_XX.properties files. Just all the localized configuration in one file that supports UTF-8!

The answer is to set the ValidationMessageSource of your validator with your resourceBundle. For example:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" 
        p:defaultEncoding="UTF-8"
        p:basenames      ="classpath:messages"/>

<!-- JSR-303 validation-->
<bean id ="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"
        p:validationMessageSource-ref="messageSource"/>
```

All merit must be attributed to this [blog](http://www.silverbaytech.com/2013/04/16/custom-messages-in-spring-validation/) post. Not being able to read thouse characters was annoying. No more: message=\u042D\u0442\u043E \u043F\u043E\u043B\u0435 \u043D\u0435 \u043C

Answer (score 0):

Properties file in Java are per default ISO 8859-1. Characters which you cannot display this way need to use unicode escapes. To quote the javadocs of [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

> ...except the input/output stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character
>   encoding. Characters that cannot be directly represented in this
>   encoding can be written using Unicode escapes ; only a single 'u'
>   character is allowed in an escape sequence.

You will need to use unicode escapes. You can di it manually or use *native2ascii*.

Comment: This is true, beside that he’s not using legacy Java [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html), but Spring’s [MessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) that does not have this silly limitation.

Comment: Since Java 5 there seems to be some function to read properties in UTF-8. http://bordet.blogspot.com.es/2007/01/utf-8-handling-for-resourcebundle-and.html

Anyway this silly limitation is really annoying.

P.S. I find the -1 a bit hard. I really appreciate his insight even if it does not really solve the problem it helps to explain why it happend.