# How to set JSF message encoding to UTF-8?

Tags: java, jsf, utf-8, character-encoding

I have the following code for some user input validation

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{user.input}">
        <f:validator validatorId="validator.InputValidator" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton action="someaction" value="submit">
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:messages layout="table"></h:messages>
</h:form>
```

It works fine, but I need to show some UTF-8 message if user input is not valid,
how can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assume that your current problem is that characters outside the ISO-8859-1 range are been shown as [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). Is this true? I couldn't think of another reason for asking this trivial question. Yes? Then read ahead:

First, if you're still using old JSP instead of its successor Facelets, then you need to set the page encoding to UTF-8. Put this in top of every JSP:

```html
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

or configure it globally in `web.xml`:

```xml
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

If you're using Facelets, you don't need to do anything. It uses by default already UTF-8 as response encoding.

Second, if you're obtaining the messages from `.properties` files, then you need to understand that those files are by default been read using ISO-8859-1. See also [`java.util.Properties` javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

> .. the input/output stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding. Characters that cannot be directly represented in this encoding can be written using Unicode escapes ; only a single 'u' character is allowed in an escape sequence. The `native2ascii` tool can be used to convert property files to and from other character encodings.

So, you need to write down the the characters outside the ISO-8859-1 range by [Unicode escape sequences](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Syntax/Unicode_Escape_Sequences). E.g. instead of

```
some.dutch.text = Één van de wijken van Curaçao heet Saliña.
```

you need to write

```
some.dutch.text = \u00c9\u00e9n van de wijken van Cura\u00e7ao heet Sali\u00f1a.
```

This can be automated by using `native2ascii` tool.

As a completely different alternative, you can supply JSF a custom [`ResourceBundle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) implementation with a custom [`Control`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html) which reads the files using UTF-8. This is in more detail expanded in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645491/i18n-with-utf-8-encoded-properties-files-in-jsf-2-0-appliaction/3646601#3646601) and [this blog](http://jdevelopment.nl/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/). This works only whenever you're providing validation messages by your own as for example `requiredMessage` instead of overriding JSF default validation messages. Other than that (i.e. you need it for `<message-bundle>` files), then you really need to use the `native2ascii` tool.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)