# Is it possible to use Application Scope with JSF's ResourceBundle

Tags: jsf-2, scope, resourcebundle

We are currently adding support for a 2nd language in our application, and we load the message bundle in a Session Scoped bean like so

```
bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(languageSetting.getLanguage().getPropertiesFileName(), new OurCustomBundleControl());
```

This allows us to retrieve messages like so:

```
public String get(final String key) {
    return bundle.getString(key);
}
```

The `languageSetting` variable is a class that we use to switch the language, which is done via a control on the page.

We are doing things this way for two reasons, firstly we need to use non-UTF-8 characters by overriding the Control class (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)), and we are also using CDI to manage scopes.

Our assumption is that the message bundle class can only be Session scoped because different users will need to have different languages selected, but we are concerned that performance wise it may be preferable to have it Application scoped.

Is is possible to have a custom resource bundle with an Application scope? is it recommended?

I'm thinking it may be possible to somehow specify the message bundle in `faces-config` which is the usual way, but we would still need to override the `Control` class. And then we could switch the language by switching the locale with `UIViewRoot#setLocale()`.

Another option might be to have two message bundles, then have a conditional statement in the `get` method?

Comment: Are you aware of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3645491? No need for manual resource bundle management in beans anymore.

Comment: Yes thanks, I actually came across that same post here: http://jdevelopment.nl/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/ later in the day and it's working like a dream, thanks.