# maven i18n JSF2 UTF8 encoding

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, utf-8

In my application (Jdk 1.7, JSF2, Maven 3, Spring...), I tried the following configuration to set the UTF-8 encoding to my messages_xx_XX.properties i18n files:

[i18n with UTF-8 encoded properties files in JSF 2.0 appliaction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3646601/5695673)

I don't have problems running the app in Eclipse, but when I try to run in a standalone Tomcat 7 config (in order to deploy the application on Openshift platform), I have the following error:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name fr.gf.predic.web.i18n.BundleUTF8Perso, locale fr_FR
```

Here is my application config:

the `faces-config.xml`:

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>currentDate</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.Date</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>fr-FR</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>fr-FR</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>

    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>

    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>fr.gf.predic.web.i18n.BundleUTF8Perso</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

the property file is in the folder: `fr/gf/predic/i18n/textes` under the `src/main/resources` folder.

In my `pom.xml`, I have the following plugin filtering this folder:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
                <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.less</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I don't see where the problem can come from.

Comment: `fr/gf/predic/i18n/textes` does not match `fr.gf.predic.web.i18n`.

Comment: Yes, but `fr.gf.predic.web.i18n` is the package where the class is. And, in the class, the constructor of the bundle is like this: `setParent(ResourceBundle.getBundle(fr.gf.predic.i18n.textes.message...)`

Comment: after investigating, if I remove the plugin maven-war-plugin in the pom and I put this: `<resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>`, it works...